# manipulating the loaded contents with Jquery. MVC ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am currently working on a project that requires me to use an MVC concept with ASP.NET. I am trying to load a specific content from a page called `Event.cshtml` to a particular div in `Detail.cshtml`. I have successfully loaded the contents on the designated page. However the issue is I can't manipulate the loaded contents.

I have this code on the `Event.cshtml`: 
http://pastebin.com/B4bxfjZt

I have this code prepared inside the `Detail.cshtml` as the location where to load the content:

```
<div class="lightbox" border="0" style="text-align: center; background-color:white; border-radius: 10px;" >
    <div class="contents"></div>

</div>
```

At the bottom of `Detail.cshtml` I have this Jquery to loaded the desire content and where:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){



        $(".contents").load('/Prime/Event/2014-2849?url=project .form');

        $(window).load(function () {
            hideContacts();
            $("#eventdate").datepicker();
            $('#starttime').timepicker({
                'step': 15,
                'minTime': '06:00 AM',
                'maxTime': '10:00 PM',
                'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
                'scrollDefaultTime': '12:00 PM'
            });
            $('.lightbox').bPopup(
           {
               position: [40,120],
           }
           );

        });

        alert('about to hit' + ("#sbt"));
        ("#sbt").click(function(e){

            alert('I was clicked!');
        });

    });

</script>
```

The issue is that `#eventdate`, `#starttime` are not manipulable. I have been stuck on this issue for a week.

I will be grateful for any help or insights.

Comment: Can you please explain what your code is supposed to do? Especially the expected order of events as `load` is asynchronous and potentially finishes after the `$(window).load` :)

Comment: The $(window).load is to ensure that the pop up only happens once the window is completely load. load in jquery executed when the document is ready not necessarily when it is completely loaded. I use such case to prevent executing the function early in my other project and it works well. In additional I disable the window load and it doesnt not made any different as to why I cant manipulating the loaded contents.

Comment: Of course removing `$(window).load` makes a difference... It makes the situation *even worse*. If your `#eventdate` element is inside the loaded form, it is trying to connect the handler before that form is loaded. I will restore my previous answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not get a `window.load` event when you expect. You are also missing a `$` on `$("#sbt").`

Use a callback in `load()`:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $(".contents").load('/Prime/Event/2014-2849?url=project .form', function () {
          // Do this stuff only after `load` completes
          hideContacts();
          $("#eventdate").datepicker();
          $('#starttime').timepicker({
              'step': 15,
                  'minTime': '06:00 AM',
                  'maxTime': '10:00 PM',
                  'timeFormat': 'h:i A',
                  'scrollDefaultTime': '12:00 PM'
          });
          $('.lightbox').bPopup({
              position: [40, 120],
          });
          // Moved this inside the load event handler
          alert('about to hit' + ("#sbt"));
          $("#sbt").click(function (e) {
              alert('I was clicked!');
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: The window load are use to ensure  that the actions only tried to perform once everything is completed loaded. I use similar structure in one of my other assignment and it works well.

Comment: I edit my code following yours. The main issue here is that #eventdate,#starttime,#sbt which are all an ids tags of Event.cshtml and I loaded them in Detail.cshtml and yet I am not able to manipulate them

Comment: Please put your *latest/current* code into a JSFiddle so I can check for errors/typos/problems.

Comment: Thanks man!! I caught the mistake. Your code is correct. I really appreciate the help!!